# Can I update a Dell Venue Pro to Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: 8.1, 7.5, update

I have a Nokia Lumia 520, which has nearly the same hardware configuration as the Dell Venue Pro has, but the thing is that the Venue Pro has Windows Phone 7.5 as its built-in OS. Can I upgrade it Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: @Indrek "Will my phone update to 8" and "Will my phone update to 8.1" are different questions with different answers.

Comment: @caschw Not quite, the answers are closely related. If a phone cannot update to 8.0, it cannot update to 8.1 either. And as the answers to the linked question explain, no WP7 device can be updated to 8.0 (and thus, to 8.1). Hence, this question already has an answer.

Comment: @Indrek You are correct, I misread the question earlier.

Answer (score 3):

**No**, you cannot upgrade the Dell Venue Pro to Windows Phone 8.

No Windows Phone 7 device is able to run Windows Phone 8 due to hardware requirements.

Answer (score 1):

No, You cant due to hardware limitations. You can however upgrade to WP 7.8 which supports smaller tiles.